# Python app returns MySQL data 3 times instead of 1

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a simple MySQL table with the following meta and content

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| School | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+---------+--------+
| id | Name    | School |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | Artem   | AU     |
|  2 | Simon   | AAU    |
|  3 | Steffen | AU     |
+----+---------+--------+
```

from which I'm trying to fetch all data using a simple python app, however my output is returned like this when I run the app(click to enlarge photo):

[image]

but what I expect it to return is  `(1, 'Artem', 'AU'), (2, 'Simon', 'AAU'), (3, 'Steffen', 'AU')` only.

The Python code is

```
import MySQLdb

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def getFromDB():
    data = []
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="ip",
                      user="user",
                      passwd="pw",
                      db="db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM students")
    students = cur.fetchall()
    for student in students:
        data.append(students)
    return data


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(getFromDB())
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `data.append(students)` is the problem.

Comment: Why not use the Django ORM?

Comment: @IainShelvington This is my very first time trying out Django - what is ORM?

Comment: @Artem Create a model and the use the model to query your database. The Django tutorial gives a good foundation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this part:

```
for student in students:
    data.append(students)
```

Did you find any problem? `students` have three items, so this loop will run three times. But you append `students` to `data`. That means, you get a new list:

`data = [students, students, students]`

Extract it, you could see:

`data = [(student1, student2, student3), (student1, student2, student3), (student1, student2, student3)]`

It's easy to fix your code, just remove a character --- `s`

```
for student in students:
    data.append(student)
```

In fact, you could just use one line to do this convert:

```
data = list(cur.fetchall())
```

But, as comment said, if you use django, you should try to learn how to use django built-in ORM.

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    School = models.CharField(max_length=45)

Student.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That made sense. I'm going to look more into ORM.

Answer (score 0):

students (before the for loop), should contain the result you are looking for - .fetchall() will return a list of found rows, which you can access as students[x]

Comment: So basically removing the `for student in students:data.append(students)` part and `return students`?